# can someone pls help me to find out opensource drupal themes which has user login options and file upload

Tags: drupal, plugins, content-management-system, themes, drupal-modules

i have browsed through a few themes but culdnt find any.can someone pls help to find out drupal themes which has user login options , am trying to build a site where users can have their own account and upload their files whenever they want.

is it possible to use any theme and add login plugin but am doubtful that if i use login or user file upload plugin i may feel difficulties in customizing it.

Theme with login & file upload functioanlities. like this

http://www.themesnap.com/premium-drupal-themes/droupon.html

Comment: sorry, no, it's not in the stackoverflow rules...

Comment: Drupal already supports user accounts and file uploads with any theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes are (usually) only styling front-end of your site. Drupal by default (must) have users system login/registration form and all other functionality related to users.

When you activate your new theme logout and go to page "/user" to see your loging form. There are also "/user/register", "/user/password" and some other related with user account functionality.

Will your custom theme also style login/registration/pass forgot forms (pages) or not - that's another question. But they will definitely exist. But even if they are not styled you can put on your own some extra CSS to style them.

For Drupal 7 file field is already included in basic installation (for D6 you have to install extra module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield ).